# How to send PUT request with variable path parameter AND request parameter in the same endpoint with JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, request-mapping, http-request-parameters

I'm using a Jmeter 5.3, and a need send PUT request with **PathVariable** **AND** **RequestParam** in the same endpoint.

Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authorize/{iduser}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> authorizeUser(
            @PathVariable Integer iduser,
            @RequestParam(value = "idstore") Integer idstore,
            @RequestParam(value = "typerequest") Integer type)
            { ...
```

I use a HTTP REQUEST component

```
PUT -> <URL>/authorize/${iduser}
```

Parameters:

```
name      | Value
idstore   | 139
type      | 1
```

But a receive **400 BAD REQUEST**.

```
{"timestamp":1595881241767,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request",
"message":"Required Integer parameter 'idstore' is not present","path":"/authorize/175"}
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: error says there's also `idplace`

Comment: sorry, I paste other stack. Error says about idstore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the parameters as part of the path:

```
PUT -> <URL>/authorize/${iduser}?idstore=139&typerequest=1
```

also maybe you need to send Content-type header with application/json